# Expressing expectation for future career

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

In a paragraph, I have written about my past experiences, plans, and my interests. As a conclusion I want a single sentence to explicitly express my expectation for my future career.

I can simply say "I hope to become a researcher in the future". But I want to make a stronger single sentence which (1) conveys that I am determined about what I want to be in the future and (2) emphasize that it is for my "future career" (not just some happening in the future).

Is the following sentence appropriate and correct? Are the prepositions in it correctly chosen?

> According to my aforementioned experiences, plans, and interests, I see myself as a researcher in my future career

What other choices do I have?

Comment: Instead of saying that you *see yourself* as a researcher in the future, you might want to indicate that you are *working towards becoming* a researcher.  You don't have to use those words exactly but you probably will want to use some *active* language to express that.  I see myself as the ruler of Atlantis in the future.  What am doing to work toward that goal?  Nothing.  It's just how I see myself.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to say "future career"?  Is it different from your current occupation or training? Also, ***According** to my **aforementioned** experiences and interests* is a bit too wordy and unnecessary. It seems like you are trying too hard to impress someone with your English. Just my opinion. Why not go with something direct, "Based on my experiences and interests"?

Comment: @EllieK Couldn't agree more.

Comment: @AIQ Yes there is two particular reason. First I am asked to mention that. Second I want to say that research is not just a temporary activity that I just intend to do for achieving an academic degree. It may that someone is a researcher now but later becomes a lecturer who only teaches students. So I need to say that  I am currently a researcher and I intend to remain a researcher in my future career.

Comment: @alireza Maybe you should have added all those details in the question. Provide as much context as possible, please. Say something to the effect of "After completing my degree, I intend to pursue a career in the research field, where I'd have the opportunity to work on various policies/programs ... " Also, see edits to the answer.

Comment: @AIQ and EllieK,
In addition to good suggestion of AIQ, is "I am striving towards being a professional researcher in my future career" also a good choice? Since I am now a researcher, I changed "become" with "be" so that it does not imply something that I am not now and will become in the future.

Comment: @alireza Side comment: In many places of the world, a post-graduate degree like a master's or PhD can be considered equivalent to 1 or 2 years of work experience in an office. So, if you've done any of these, consider (based on your location) that you *can* say that you are already a *professional* researcher. Much more so if you have publications ...

Comment: @AIQ Yes you are right. What if I change "professional" with "eminent". I don't think that I am an eminent researcher now.

Comment: By the way "more stronger" is not idiomatic, Just use "stronger" or for emphasis "much stronger".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you have some education/training that's related to research? If that's the case, you are already a researcher, maybe just not a good one.

You could say the following, which emphasizes that you are *already on the path* towards becoming a *successful* researcher. It leaves no room for doubt.

> I am an aspiring economist / research analyst / writer, looking to be part of ...

If you'd like, you could use "young" in there, too, to qualify the statement a bit.

I'd discourage using the "I see myself as [...] in the future" statement. It just doesn't feel authentic and personal anymore. It's a very generic statement that lacks personality.

You could say something more specific; something that shows you are determined and laser focused:

> My research interests include studying the behavior of ..
> I plan to study the impact of ...
> I have a strong interest in conducting policy research, with a focus on ...

Usually, statements like "I see myself as [...] in the future" are responses to questions like "Where do you see yourself in the next 5 years?"

Be bold.

> In the next five years, I am going to complete my Data Science certification [or diploma] and use my knowledge and training of data analytics in understanding the effects of social assistance programs (such as child care benefits, children's fitness tax credits, etc.) on income inequality at the household level.

**Edit:** OP says in the comment

> Actually I have noted all of these in other sentences of a paragraph where I have written about my research experiences and interests and need just a single sentence for concluding that paragraph.

If one already has research experience, then they are already in their research career (even if at the very early stages). There's no need for "future career", unless one is in a different field altogether.

You could maybe say something like:

> Based on my experiences and interests, I am certain that I'd like to pursue career in economic research outside of academia.

Comment: Actually I have noted all of these in other sentences of a paragraph where I have written about my research experiences and interests and need just a single sentence for concluding that paragraph.

Comment: @alireza If you have research experience, then you are already in your *career*. You don't need "future career".